# Hibernate mappedBy and ManyToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa

I'm starting from scratch a new project and i got this problem which i cannot solve. I have three entities, and they all have a manytomany relationship with each other. There is the Cluster:

```
@Entity
@Component
@Table(name = "clusterEntity")
public class Cluster {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @ManyToMany
      @JoinTable(name="cluster_user",
          joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="cluster_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
          inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private List<User> users_cluster;

    @ManyToMany
      @JoinTable(name="cluster_sito",
          joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="cluster_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
          inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="sito_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private List<Sito> sitos;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Cluster{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name +
                ", users='" + users_cluster.toString() +
                '}';
    }
}
```

This is the User:

```
@Entity
@Component
@Table(name = "userEntity")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password_hash", nullable = false)
    private String passwordHash;

    @Column(name = "role", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;

    @Column(name = "G1", nullable = true)
    private String G1;

    @Column(name = "G2", nullable = true)
    private String G2;

    @Column(name = "G3", nullable = true)
    private String G3;

    @Column(name = "G4", nullable = true)
    private String G4;

    @Column(name = "G5", nullable = true)
    private String G5;

    @Column(name = "G6", nullable = true)
    private String G6;

    @Column (name = "access_token", nullable = true)
    private String access_token;

    @Column (name = "refresh_token", nullable = true)
    private String refresh_token;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPasswordHash() {
        return passwordHash;
    }

    public void setPasswordHash(String passwordHash) {
        this.passwordHash = passwordHash;
    }

    public Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getG1() {
        return G1;
    }

    public void setG1(String g1) {
        G1 = g1;
    }

    public String getG2() {
        return G2;
    }

    public void setG2(String g2) {
        G2 = g2;
    }

    public String getG3() {
        return G3;
    }

    public void setG3(String g3) {
        G3 = g3;
    }

    public String getG4() {
        return G4;
    }

    public void setG4(String g4) {
        G4 = g4;
    }

    public String getG5() {
        return G5;
    }

    public void setG5(String g5) {
        G5 = g5;
    }

    public String getG6() {
        return G6;
    }

    public void setG6(String g6) {
        G6 = g6;
    }

    public String getAccess_token() {
        return access_token;
    }

    public void setAccess_token(String access_token) {
        this.access_token = access_token;
    }

    public String getRefresh_token() {
        return refresh_token;
    }

    public void setRefresh_token(String refresh_token) {
        this.refresh_token = refresh_token;
    }

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="users_cluster")
    private List<User> users_cluster;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="users_sito")
    private List<User> users_sito;

    public User(){}

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", email='" + email.replaceFirst("@.*", "@***") +
                ", passwordHash='" + passwordHash.substring(0, 10) +
                ", role=" + role +
                '}';
    }
}
```

This is the Sito:

```
@Entity
@Component
@Table(name = "sitoEntity")
public class Sito {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @ManyToMany
      @JoinTable(name="sito_user",
          joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="sito_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
          inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private List<User> users_sito;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Sito{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name+
                ", users='" + users_sito.toString()+
                '}';
    }
}
```

When i try compiling with maven i get the following error about mappedBY, as if it was written on both side of the relation, but in fact it is written only on one side:

Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal use of mappedBy on both sides of the relationship: User.users_cluster

Anyone has any ideaof what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You have told hibernate that your relationship from user to list<user> is mapped in the class user (itself). This would create some kind of recursion. I don't think you can use the mappedBy attribute in this case. It is usually used when having a relation between entity A and B to tell which side is the owner. But you are having a relaiton from entity User to itself. Defining an owner with mappedBy makes no sense (at least to me).

Comment: BTW: While I don't really understand what your entities are modelling you wrote that your 3 Entities have ManyToMany relationships which each other, but in User it only has 2 ManyToMany relationships with itself. Shouldn't User have a List<Cluster> and List<Sito> instead of two List<User>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Clustor

As far as I can see the `Cluster` entity is annotated correctly except some kine of naming convention. Instead of

```
private List<User> users_cluster;
```

I would recommend using

```
private List<User> users;
```

The list contains users so it should be named to reflect that; good naming is the best documentation, (imo).

## User

This entity seems to be correctly annotated but the references are  wrong as they are self referencing. So the entity should be modified as follows if you want to create a many-to-many relationship between the thre entities:

```
public class User {

    // ...

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="users")
    private List<Cluster> clusters;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="users")
    private List<Sito> sitos;

    // getters + setters


}
```

## Sito

Here too I made a small modification as follows:

```
public class Sito {

     // ...

     @ManyToMany
     @JoinTable(name="sito_user",
          joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="sito_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
          inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private List<User> users;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "sitos")
    private List<Cluster> clusters;


    // getters + setters
}
```

Now your three entities should be related to each other as you desired.